# In chrome, ctrl + mouse wheel zooming is not working in wordpress website

Tags: google-chrome, zooming, mousewheel

In chrome, ctrl + mouse wheel zooming is not working in wordpress website and ctrl + and ctrl - also working.please anyone can help.

Comment: share the link of webpage please

Comment: [http://linkseniors.com/sailingschool/sailingschool/] all other browsers zooming is working accept chrome

Comment: it is working on my chrome 47.0.2526.106 m, wish i could help.

Comment: if i will add jquery library it works but design will go. please let me know solution of this issue.

Comment: mine also chrome 47 but its not woring

Comment: problem is not clear mate, try to debug it and narrow down to the issue or create a fiddle maybe, SO is always ready to help you just need to make the issue clear

Comment: i added jquery library so its working just now i removed check now.if i will add jquery library it effects to design so i removed

Comment: i see the issue now, let me check mate

Comment: are you sure you have not disabled ctrl+mousewheel in script, it is quite easy to do so

Comment: no i didnot  disable ctrl+mousewheel in script

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It appears I was calling a JavaScript scroll binding function. Maybe you are too.

In this case remove this code:

```
$.browserSelector();
if($("html").hasClass("chrome")) {
    $.smoothScroll();
}
```